# Geometric characterizations of conformal maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

I have some fairly basic questions with regards to conformal structures/maps -- I apologize if they are on the basic side for MO, but I figured I might get some clarity here.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Riemannian manifolds and $F : X \to Y$ is a diffeomorphism.  Then $F$ is *conformal* if there is some positive smooth function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g_X(v,w) = f(p) g_Y(dF_p(v), dF_p(w))$ (where here $g_X$ is the metric on $X$ and $g_Y$ is the metric on $Y$) for all $p \in X$ and all $v,w \in T_p X$.  Directly from the definition of angles between tangent vectors in Riemannian manifolds, we see that conformal maps preserve angles.  Maybe if $X$ and $Y$ are oriented, we should also insist that $F$ preserves the orientation.

A *circle* in a Riemannian manifold is the set of all points of some fixed distance from a given point.  A diffeomorphism between Riemannian manifolds *sends circles to circles* if the image of every circle is again a circle.

I have heard that for the flat plane, round sphere, and hyperbolic plane, the set of conformal automorphisms are exactly the diffeomorphisms that send circles to circles and I am wondering to what extent this characterization continues to hold for other geometries.

> Does this characterization hold in general (considering codimension 1
> spheres instead of circles), or in general in dimension 2, or for
> constant curvature metrics (maybe just in dimension 2)?

In a similar vein, I was wondering:

> Is being angle-preserving equivalent to being conformal (perhaps under some suitable restrictions on the geometry/topology)?

Maybe there is a direct definition of a conformal structure as a way of measuring angles (instead of as an equivalence class of metrics where $g \sim f g$ for $f$ positive) that exists and would help clear up my confusion, but I couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: At least in the case of non-complete surfaces, I think it is not hard to use the Riemann mapping theorem to see that a conformal map from the unit disc to some other sub-domain of the complex plane need not send circles to circles. I believe in general a conformal map only sends codimension one spheres to spheres “up to first order.”

Comment: 1. What you called a "circle" is usually called a "metric sphere." 2. It is easy to see that for every Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and any non-identity conformal automorphism $\phi$ of $(M,g)$, there is a positive function $f$ on $M$ such that $\phi$ **does not** send metric spheres in $(M,fg)$ to metric spheres in $(M,fg)$ (but, of course, $\phi$ is still a conformal automorphism of $(M,fg)$). 3. However, if $\phi$ sends metric spheres to metric spheres, it is a conformal automorphism. 4. All in all, the question is more appropriate for MathStackExchange than MO.

Comment: Hello @MoisheKohan. I agree with you on all the points but the second and 4 ones. For the second point, what if $\phi$ is an isometry (e.g a non trivial translation in the euclidean plane)? For the 4th point: in terms of structure, I think that the conformal structure is not a question for the new coming. The real question, I think, is: is the asker has the needed background to grasp the real meaning of a conformal structure (which comprises some good understanding of gauge theory (principal bundles))? This by looking at the way the question is formulated.

Comment: @EricArnéoVespiraKengne I'm more than happy to hear about principal bundles, and I'd love hear about (and/or have a reference to) the "real meaning of a conformal structure" :-)

Comment: @EricArnéoVespiraKengne There is nothing special about translations, the argument will work just as well. And one does not need bundles to understand conformality, although, it does not hurt, of course.

Comment: @MoisheKohan you are right when saying that one does not need bundles to understand conformality if one looks at it with the analyst glasses: it is just a regular section of the group of units of the algebra of smooth functions on a given smooth manifold. But, to understand the conformality geometrically, (that's understand a conformal structure), I don't know if there is any way don't using gauge theory...

Comment: Sorry, it's my viewpoint

Comment: And hello @MoisheKohan

Comment: Hello @I_frost. Me too I like talking about the conformal structure. But I think that it isn't the right place here (MO) to talk about in this sense. Perhaps it would well to create a discussion about it (if it'snt) and invite me... In any case, geometric Structures are marvellous, that's sure.

Comment: Hello @I_FROST.
 I hope I did not hurt you with my last comment on your post on MO by asking you to create a discussion and especially, to invite me !!! If so, all my apologizes. Elsewhere, I'm planning to create on MO, a discussion on the Riemann-Cartan Geometry of Parabolic type (which are a class of geometries, generalising conformal geometry; e.g, Möbius and projective geometries are examples of Parabolic geometry). I will be happy to welcome you. 
Again, I apologize sincerely, if I offended you.

Comment: @EricArnéoVespiraKengne I don't even know what I would be offended by :-)

Comment: Riemann-Cartan structure of real rank 2 is just a kind of "framed" tractor space associated with a lorentzian conformal structure (arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7559 and reference therein). A "Riemann-Cartan structure of real rank 2m" having to be a natural generalization for which the space of tractors is of dimension n+2m; this tractor space being associated with a pseudo-Riemannian conformal structure of real dimension n and index m. 
**Note** : this comment is taken from one of my comments on MO. I don't know if it's a good practice.

Comment: About the discussion, my actual framework don't allow me to manage it as I wanted. Very sorry for that.